# GridView item template linkbutton catch on code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, itemtemplate

I have a gridview in my asp.net project and i used item template like;

```
<asp:TemplateField>
                  <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID = "lnkSil" runat="server" CommandName="bla" 
CommandArgument='<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>' Text= "Sil" ></asp:LinkButton>
                  </ItemTemplate>
                  </asp:TemplateField>
```

And I want to catch this from code behind and i used below code ;

```
((Button)e.Row.Cells[1].Controls[0]).Attributes.Add("onclick", "return confirm('Bu kaydi silmek istediginizden emin misiniz?')");
```

but I'm failed  how can i catch this controls on code behind like this

also i tried

```
((LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[1].Controls[0]).Attributes.Add("onclick", "return confirm('Bu kaydi silmek istediginizden emin misiniz?')");
```

Comment: is there a reason you cannot do it in the markup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to get access to the event without javascript then use the GridView1_RowCommand.

```
 protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
 {
     int currentRowIndex = Int32.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
     LinkButton bf = (LinkButton)gv.Rows[currentRowIndex].Cells[1].Controls[0];
     ...
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
protected void gvMyGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs e)
 {
 if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) {
 LinkButton lnkSil = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("lnkSil");
 lnkSil.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:return confirm('Bu kaydi silmek istediginizden emin misiniz?');");
     }
 }
```